# How to execute a lambda of a class passing its name as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, class, lambda, dynamic, attributes

i'm trying to do this:

I have the class Caller

```py
    class Caller:
       add = lambda a, b : a + b
       concat = lambda a, b : f'{a},{b}'
       divide = lambda a, b : a / b
       multiply = lambda a, b : a * b
```

and the function fn()

```py
    def fn(fn_to_call, *args):
    
       result = None

       if fn_to_call == 'add':
           result = Caller.add(*args)
       if fn_to_call == 'concat':
           result = Caller.concat(*args)
       if fn_to_call == 'divide':
           result = Caller.divide(*args)
       if fn_to_call == 'multiply':
           result = Caller.multiply(*args)

       return result
```

and what i would like to do, is to reduce the fn code to only one line. First, i have the thought of using a one-line if, some like

```py
    return Caller.add(*args) if fn_to_call is 'add' else Caller.concat(*args) if fn_to_call is 'concat' else Caller.divide(*args) if fn_to_call is 'divide' else Caller.multiply(*args) if fn_to_call is 'multiply' else None;
```

but , i think that was going to be a bad practice.
I realized that the name of the lambda attribute of the class Caller it will be equal to the param fn_to_call (add, concat, divide, multiply)
So, i wanted to know if it was possible to call an attribute of the function dynamically. Something like:

```py
def fn(fn_to_call, *args):
   return Caller."some_magic_method"(fn_to_call, *args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class's `__dict__` property:

```
def fn(fn_to_call, *args):
    return Caller.__dict__[fn_to_call](*args)
```

or the getattr function:

```
def fn(fn_to_call, *args):
    return getattr(Caller,fn_to_call)(*args)
```